# Linux as a router for public networks

Tags: linux, router, routing, gateway, wide-area-network

My ISP had given me a /30 network. Later, when I wanted more public ips, I requested for a /29 network. I was told to keep using my earlier /30 network on the interface which is facing ISP, and the newly given /29 network should be used on the other interface which connects to my NAT router and servers.

This is what I got from the isp:

```
WAN IP: 179.xxx.4.128/30
CUSTOMER IP : 179.xxx.4.130
ISP GATEWAY IP:179.xxx.4.129
SUBNET : 255.255.255.252

LAN IPS: 179.xxx.139.224/29
GATEWAY IP :179.xxx.139.225
SUBNET : 255.255.255.248
```

I have a Ubuntu pc which has two interfaces. So I am planning to do the following:

```
eth0 will be given 179.xxx.4.130/30 gateway 179.xxx.4.129
eth1 will be given  179.xxx.139.225/29
```

And I will have the following in the `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

These will be iptables rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

My clients which have the ips `179.xxx.139.226/29` and `179.xxx.139.227/29` will be made to use `179.xxx.139.225/29` as gateway.

Will this configuration work for me? Any comments? If it works, what iptables rules can I use to have a bit of security?

*P.S. Both networks are non-private and there is no NATing.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very clear how this is set up / how you think it will work ("which connects to my NAT router....there is no NATing").

But from what I can see this is likely to break in strange and esoteric ways.

Consider, a client outside connects to 179.xxx.139.225, but the reply might come from 179.xxx.4.129 - you certainly won't be able to run any stateful firewalling.

While it is quite possible to [configure Linux to handle the routing](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) sensibly, it'd be a lot simlper to partition the networks across 2 routers - even if one of them is a virtual machine.

Comment: NAT router will have 179.xxx.139.226 as ip (it'll exist in 179.xxx.139.224/29 network), and default gateway for it is 179.xxx.139.225 (the one I want to set up).

Comment: The router, the ISP should have set up to connect different WAN networks, should be installed by me. So, now I should have a router to forward traffic between my old WAN subnet (/30) and the new one (/29).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the iptables configuration which I have no idea about, I think it will work for you but you shouldn't forget the routing table of the Linux system to make ethics as the default.